# Multiple concurrent views of a single list

Tags: list, view, calendar-view

[image: web-part]I am new to SharePoint!

I have a list, for which I have created a new view named as 'calendar'.
Now I want to display the default view and calendar view side by side.

Created a 2-column sections, for each I added that same list. For one, I changed the view to the 'calendar' view then re-publish. But the list on the other web part now also shows in 'calendar' view too.
And when I changed it back to default view, the other one also switches to default list view too.

Is my desired layout impossible to achieve? How can I achieve the intended layout?

I have added a screenshot extract of what I had done, and where I can see "web-part" but do not see anything about "app-part"

Answer (score 0):

Insert the app part into the second column, then edit the web-part. From there you can change the view to the one which you want to display in that app part or if you haven't created it yet then modify current view in the web part editing menu. This will not change the actual views for the list but it will change the web-part displaying view for this individual web part.

Comment: thanx for answering. am new to SP so frankly having a difficult time understanding this answer. will try as best i can, but it would be better if have some kind of screenshots.
for example, i need to google app-part vs web-part cos have not seen any reference to app-part so far

Answer (score 0):

You can try below steps to use same list with different views on the page. If you have already added lists(web-parts) to both the columns, follow below steps :

1. Select edit web-part option for the one of the list for which you wanted to change/set different view.
   [image]
2. Now you can view/edit web-part properties for this web-part. Here you have to choose view you wanted to set from the available list views.

[image]

3. Once you have selected view click on **Apply** at bottom of the web-part properties section.

[image]

Now, after saving web-part properties just close the properties tab and save the page.

[image]

Hope these steps will help you to achieve desired output/layout. :)